# can't properly create motion tweens between two keyframes in flash CS4

Tags: animation, adobe-flash

I'm trying to create a flash animation of a wing flapping using three keyframes. The first keyframe is at frame 1. I then created a second keyframe at frame 5 by pressing F6, and then I created another keyframe at frame 10 by pressing F6. At frame 5, I rotated the wing so that it is going up. Frame 10 is the same as frame 1.

frame 1:
[image]

frame 5: [image]
frame 10: [image]

I right clicked on a frame between frames 5 and 10 and then clicked the first option, "Create Motion Tween"; I then performed the same action on a frame between frames 1 and 5. When I preview or test the movie, there is no transition between the frames. From frame 1 to 5, there  is supposed to be a transition of the wing flapping up. From frame 5 to 10, there is supposed to be a transition of the wing flapping downwards to its initial position. Instead, when I test the movie, the wing remains still until frame 5 and instantly goes to its "wing up state" and when it gets to frame 10, instantly goes to its "wing down state".

Here is what the timeline looks like after I've made the changes mentioned above:

[image]

I'm using Flash CS4 to make the animation but the tutorial I'm following is using Flash CS3. I know I can use other methods to create the motion tween but I want to know why the method I'm using isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do to emulate the CS3 behavior is create a Classic Tween (which should also be on your context menu).

The purpose of a Motion Tween is allow you to control and define the animation directly to the object using the Motion Editor, without having to create all your keyframes on the timeline. This was a [new feature in CS4](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flash/10.0_UsingFlash/WS9F717870-8AED-438d-B324-44ACCE6871E8a.html), so won't be mentioned in a CS3 tutorial. If you create a Motion Tween then don't touch the Motion Editor, you have the tween, but not the motion.

That little switch of vocabulary caused quite a bit of confusion, so you're in good company.

Comment: On frame 5, the wing has been rotated up AND is scaled down. Will classic tween create transition frames between frame 1 and 5 as the wing is rotating and decreasing in size?

Comment: hey I tried classic tween but its not creating transition frames for the rotation and scaling

Comment: Check your steps carefully. Be sure that your object is a movie clip symbol. The tween works as advertised, so this might be time to search for Tween in the Help.

Comment: I got it to work! The wing has a wing movie clip within its own movie clip editing window. I changed it to a graphic symbol and it works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. That's what we're here for. :)